# What apps can fully load 32-bit floating point DNGs?

Tags: lightroom, hdr, dng

Lightroom Mobile's HDR feature produces a somewhat uncommon type of DNGs - 32-bit floating point ones.

I tried loading one into Photoshop. I was presented with an Adobe Camera Raw window where I could select loading as 8-bit integer or as 16-bit integer. Both of those obviously lose a lot of dynamic range.

Photomatix and Luminance HDR straight up refused to load the DNG.

**So, if I don't want to tonemap directly in Lr Mobile, what are my options?**

Note: I run Windows.

Comment: Is this still a problem? Adobe has likely updated their software since this question was written.